# How can i trim URLs to root domain? i'm using notepad++

Tags: url, subdomain, edit, trim

I have a list of domain name with parameters

```
http://www.anandinfra.net/project.php?id=2
http://artlinkinteriors.com/page.php?id=1
http://www.rabinmukherjeecollege.in/notice_details.php?id=1
```

I need to find other parts with domain and I have to replace those parts.

Finally my result should look as follows. Expected result:

```
http://www.anandinfra.net/
http://artlinkinteriors.com/
http://www.rabinmukherjeecollege.in/
```

How can I attain this result?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can create a CNAME in the DNS setting with the
http://www.anandinfra.net/project.php?id=2 pointing to http://www.anandinfra.net/

and same for the rest

Comment: `CNAME` records map names to names, not URLs to URLs. Plus the OP probably wants to just change the strings, not do DNS settings.

Answer (score -1):

In whatever programming language you use (which you don't disclose), find the relevant library handling URLs and use it to mutate them. DO NOT attempt to do that by string manipulation.

Comment: im using notepad++

Comment: Which is not a programming language. This website is for programming related questions, so if you are not prepared/willing to write a program (that can then be discussed and improved here), then your question is most probably offtopic, and you may get more answers on [su]. No matter where you post, please make sure your question has enough details on what and how you want to do a certain things. If an editor is the only thing you have at hand, specific it. There may be a solution with it, or not, but it is important to know which tools you are prepared to use.